# Unable to save base 64 Image in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to save base64 image that is coming from the ajax post (blade file). Below is the code that I am using to save the data but it is giving 500 error.

```js
public function add_ref_images_first(Request $request){
        $fileName = "";
        $end_url = "";
        $count = 0;
        $folder_name = 'PUBP' . time();
        foreach ($request->images as $data){
            $image_64 = $data['src']; //your base64 encoded data
            $extension = explode('/', explode(':', substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ';')))[1])[1];   // .jpg .png .pdf
            $replace = substr($image_64, 0, strpos($image_64, ',')+1);
//
//            // find substring fro replace here eg: data:image/png;base64,
//
            $image = str_replace($replace, '', $image_64);
            $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
            $ref_image_id = 'PUBR'.time().$count++.'.'.$extension;
            $fileName = base64_decode($image)->storeAs($folder_name, $ref_image_id , ['disk' => 'my_uploaded_files']);
            if($imageName){
                $end_url = $end_url.$imageName.',';
            }
        }
        return response()->json(['url' => $end_url, 'id' => '1']);
    }
```

Is there issue with the code?

Comment: check project_directory/storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: I am getting this Erro Call to a member function storeAs() on string, Bcoz I am sending base64 to store

Answer (score 0):

instead of the line

```
  $fileName = base64_decode($image)->storeAs($folder_name, $ref_image_id , ['disk' 
=> 'my_uploaded_files']);
```

you can do :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
Storage::put($ref_image_id, base64_decode($image), 'local');
```

because basically you were trying storeAs on a string value, storeAs works on $request->file('nameFromForm')

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-file-name